# How to send message with phpmailer?

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

```
  require ("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
        require ("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php");
        require 'C:\Users\HP\Downloads\phpmailer\vendor\autoload.php';

        $mail=new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host= "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port='587';
        $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
        $mail->Username="myemail@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password="mypassword";
        $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
        $mail->From="Someone";
        $mail->AddAddress="??";
        $mail->IsHTML=true;
        $mail->Subject="Sube";
        $mail->Body="Message";
        if($mail->Send()){
        echo"Your email was sent";}
        else{
            echo "Error";}
```

So i have contact form with 4 fields(name,email,city and message).

 When the 4 fields are valid this could should be runned but i have a few questions:

**1.Should i really type my real email on Username and my real password on Password?**

**2.What email should i write on AddAdress? mine(which is the same like username) or the receiver's email?**

**3.When i fill in the form in the field email which email should i write(like username or like addAdress)?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending emails with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872078/sending-emails-with-phpmailer)

Comment: @UmairKhan yes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. If want to send from you account then yes. If your mail server doesn`t require autorization than no. Alternatively you can use the function isMail instead isSTMP (using PHP mail insted connect to another account by SMTP).
2. Receiver [addAddress PHPmailer](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addAddress)
3. What will your form do? Does it send email to you or it should send email to address from form?

Comment: it is my choice  whom to send the email and thanks i did it